What does 緩い means here?
The girls were doing "girl's talk," talking about relationships, etc..

I don't get what ユルイ means in this sentence: 楓くらいユルイ方が良いんだよ. I think means something like "you should be as 'loose' as Kae." It looks like some kind of bad joke which I don't get it.

In this scene, the adjective ユルい is used in two different ways.
The first meaning is "easygoing" or "laid-back", referring to someone's friendly and flexible attitude. It's the antonym of 厳しい or 真面目な. This ユル is the same as in the term ゆるキャラ, if you're familiar with it. The girl who said 楓くらいユルい方が良い used ユルい in this sense. This comment itself is quite normal and innocent, leaving little room for misunderstanding.
Then, another girl somehow took it as a sexual innuendo (下ネタ) and said "(私は)ユルくないし". When ユルい is used in a clearly sexual context, it means that the female genitalia is not tight enough, suggesting that the person has had many sexual experiences. However, as far as I can see from the context of this conversation, it seems unlikely that such a misunderstanding would suddenly occur. Maybe a more explicit conversation was taking place on the previous pages?
